# Grep for a particular pattern for matching ID's

Tags: linux

I am trying to run a script that will identify all complete ID's in a file. The Complete ID will contain either a 'b' or 'c' followed by 6 numbers. (i.e. b028888) I have a file that has more than 1 ID on a line, and some partial ID's. Here is the file contents:

Here is a list of some ID's

```
b028888 c948372

c039481 b0493

c34

b016396

c456039

b0291

b193
```

Lets see if this stupid thing will work!

The command that I have is:

```
grep "^[bc][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" ID.txt
```

It is only returning the first match on the line, then skipping to the next line. Any thoughts?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related to DB2

Comment: Your command works for me and prints the desired result. What are you getting?

Comment: b028888 c948372
c039481 b0493
b016396
c456039

Comment: it gives me the correct ID's, but it is including the incomplete ID of b0493. That one should be excluded from the results as it is an incomplete ID that does not contain all 6 numbers for an ID.

Comment: You could use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`, and to repeat it 6 times you could say `^[bc]\d{6}`.

Comment: I finally got it. I used grep -o "[bc][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" ID.txt..... The carat (^) was what was causing it to still give me the incomplete ID.

Comment: Ah, what he meant to say is that it matches a line only if the line begins with a valid ID.

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what `grep` is supposed to do.  If ids are bounded by spaces, you can use: `tr ' ' \\n <ID.text | grep ...` which puts each id on a separate line.

Answer (score 0):

+1 to tr, also could sed if you want.

`cat ./poop | tr ' ' \\n | grep -o "^[bc][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"`